# The phrase "The reason for starting the bounty:" is needed

Tags: feature-request

I think the phrase "The reason for starting the bounty:" is needed right before that reason is stated whenever anyone starts the bounty. Take a look [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57727/the-meaning-of-the-word-impediment-in-this-context#comment114489_57727) - when I was starting the bounty it really didn't have enough detail there. However, now the question is already answered - even though the bounty hasn't been awarded yet - and there are more than enough detail. Yet the ugly "The current answers do not contain enough detail" in the blue field under the question body states something which is no longer true. Thus, if anyone comes to look at that question's page now, especially a newcomer, he will be confused.

It would be better if it said:

> The reason for starting the bounty: The current answers do not contain
>   enough detail

or if it were put in the Past Tense:

> The reason for starting the bounty: The provided answers didn't 
>   contain enough detail

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to my typo, but I didn't quite get your answer. Can you, please, elaborate.

Comment: This "feature" would be irrelevant if [my request for 'edit' capability](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/edit-supplementary-text-on-bounty) on the bounty-placer's explanatory text were implemented. He could just edit to reflect that his reason had already been satisfied before the bounty period ended, if he cared enough about such a minor detail being "misleading" for such a short period.

Comment: Ah! I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the longest period a bounty can run for? A week? It hardly seems worth the effort to change the text because, maybe, in the last couple of days of that week, the message might sound incorrect.

Also, because of the placement of the message and its formatting and such, I think that it's already implied that the text describes the reason for *starting* the bounty rather than its continued existence.